# Как правильно использовать unicode символ рубля?

Tags: html, unicode

Как правильно использовать unicode [символ рубля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F) на странице в HTML/CSS?

Строчку ниже хром отображает как квадрат:

```
<span style=" font-family: arial; font-size: 10px: #ff0000;">&#8381</span>
```

Comment: `<span>&#8381;</span>` а вот так?

Comment: Тоже самое.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3aa0874g/

Comment: работает не везде

Comment: @mr_blond97, значит либо у вас какой-то загруженный шрифт, котором нет символа рубля, либо неправильная кодировка на сайте, нужно чтобы в head было: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: @soledar10, уж в Хроме точно должно работать, если это не какой-то очень древний хром